# Install macOS Monterey on older/ slower iMac, good for performance?

Tags: macos, imac, performance

I have an "old" late 2015 iMac 21,5" that I want to use for photography in the studio (for quality control). But even when it was new it wasn't the fastest because of the slow CPU and no SSD.

Specs:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- 21,5", late 2015
- 1,6 GHz Dual Core i5
- 8 GB Ram
- HDD
- Intel HD 6000  1536 MB

My question is, when I upgrade to Monterey, will I get a performance boost? Or will it get even worse? I've read that newer macOS is more optimized also for older machines. Is that true?

When I google for it I only find ways to install new macOS on unsupported devices. But this iMac is one of the last that is supported.

Even open the settings app is super laggy. Currently I can work with it somehow, but it could be better.

Comment: What makes those iMacs so slow is the old spinny rust hard drive. Swapping up to an SSD will bring it to life, whatever OS you put on it.

Comment: Even an external SSD as boot drive via USB 3.0 will give you an *extreme* performance boost.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same, of course an SSD will speed things up a lot. But my question goes more in the direction like: Is the new macOS version more "bloated" and will slow down that small CPU even further or is it even optimized for these low performance macs?

Answer (score 1):

There's no universal answer to that question. It depends on your workload, which applications you use, what you use them for, how often and to what extent, etc.

You could make a backup of your complete system - upgrade and test your new system. If you do not like the new system, you can roll back using the backup.